# TYPO3 Constants section disappeared

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

Inside "TypoScript Object Browser" the "Constants" section disappeared.
The "Setup" section is OK.

The only thing visible is empty: `plugin.tx_felogin_login.settings.email.layoutRootPaths`

How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Maybe there is an error with t3editor. It is an optional extension that should do code-highlighting in these fields. You can disable it.

Comment: I disabled "Editor with syntax highlighting t3editor 10.4.12" but nothing changed.

Comment: It seems you are looking into a specific template named "Spoedservice". Maybe there are no constants defined. Make sure to de-select the template by e.g. clicking on root page.

Comment: @ThomasLöffler, there should be at least some `styles.content.loginform.*`-constants with installed EXT:felogin.
I suspect a syntax error that prevents the parsing of TypoScript or causes an incorrect result. Have a look at "Template Analyzer" with "View the complete TS listing". Normally syntax errors should be shown there.